# Git: should I checkout a tagged version or master in production?

Tags: git, version-control

General question around Git.

We work in 2 week sprints and have a 4 branch process:

develop > Release-B-Name(Test) > Release-A-Name(Beta) > master

Each sprint, we create a new branch with some name (A-Z).

Each quarter, we merge the RC into master and tag that code as production ready.

Then, on the production box, we fetch and merge the latest version of master (by running `git pull origin master`) so each quarter, production is running the latest and greatest of master. This has been the historical approach.

Question: Should I be running/checking out the master branch or the tagged version of master on the production box?

I'm aware that running with a tagged version will do so in a detached state but I don't really see an issue with that, except for when needing to do a hotfix?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because the question is missing a lot of context. Git is a version control system. Are you using git as a deployment tool? If yes, why? And why does it matter that you are in a detached state in production? Do you actually intend to commit (and develop) in production? Please edit to explain this.

Comment: It's also possible that this depends entirely on your company, whether the tagged versions are "production releases" or whether production systems should always have the absolute latest of whatever you are checking out. This isn't really easily answerable by anyone unfamiliar with your group or company processes.

Comment: Maybe check with the owner where he puts his production ready code and what he wants to see on prod. It's going to be dependent on your project so it's unlikely that someone is going to give you the right answer, just a bunch of guesses.

Comment: Have updated the question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the updates. One more thing: "on the production box, we fetch and merge the latest version of master". Why "merge"? If you only ever check out the latest master, that should always be a fast-forward checkout. Why do you get merges? That sounds dangerous...

Comment: @sleske. The process is still called merging: `git merge --ff-only origin/master`

Comment: @TRiG:Yes, I hope that is what OP means by "merge".

Comment: @sleske and @TRig... I've not had to do this yet, but when seeing my manager go through the process I've only ever seen him go onto the prod box and run `git pull origin master`.  As far as I know, that just does a `git fetch` and then a `git merge`?

Comment: Ok, I see. I think I understand now. I'll try writing an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I am personally quite sceptical of using Git as a deployment tool. A real build / deployment tool will offer many things Git does not do: versioning rules, compilation/preprocessing, managing file permissions etc.. If you "deploy" using Git, these steps usually have to be manual, which sucks. However, you seem to be satisfied with your deployment process in principle, so I'll stop arguing with that.

To address your questions:

> Question: Should I be running/checking out the master branch or the
>   tagged version of master on the production box?

Both can work, but I'd prefer using a **tagged version**. The files pulled down will be exactly the same, so no difference there. However, using a tagged version is safer in some cases:

- If someone should push to master in the time between tagging and deployment, you still get the right version.
- If someone were to later just run `git pull` on production, with default settings and `master` checked out Git would fetch the latest state of `master` (whatever that is). If a tag is checked out, nothing will change.

> I'm aware that running with a tagged version will do so in a detached
>   state but I don't really see an issue with that, except for when
>   needing to do a hotfix?

I really hope you are not implying that you intend to commit (and possibly even develop) hotfixes on production? If yes, then please don't :-).

Anyway: Yes, the detached HEAD state should not be a problem. I'd actually see it as a benefit, as it makes it clear you are not supposed to commit things on production. If you really, really feel you must, you can always create and checkout a branch later when you need to (but please don't).

---

Finally, a word of advice:

> Then, on the production box, we fetch and merge the latest version of
>   master (by running git pull origin master)

Even if you insist on using Git for deployment, it is not a good idea to use `git pull`, because `git pull` will automatically perform a merge if the wrong branch was checked out before (or if you even have local commits, which you hopefully don't). The merge will cause you to have an (untested) mix of data from different branches. Rather, I'd recommend you use:

```
git fetch
git checkout MY_VERSION_TAG
```

That way, you'll get exactly the files from `MY_VERSION_TAG`. In addition to that, I'd strongly recommend you check for local modifications using `git status` before the deployment. If any are found, investigate them before deploying.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Not sure why someone down-voted you?! When I say "hotfix", I simply mean fix locally, put it into test, and when it passes, cherry-pick into master which can then be pulled in. But if I'm running a tag, I can't just pull that hotfix in, like you say. I'l give it some thought ;)

Comment: @AdamJeffers: Ok, developing hotfixes like that sounds reasonable. Also, I don't see any problem with deployment. You just treat the hotfix like any release (which you should anyway): You tag it (something like "2018-q3-hotfix33"), then checkout that tag, just as I describe above.

Comment: Ah, one more thing: Obviously the hotfix should be developed (locally) on top of the current production version (i.e. check out the pro tag, base a branch on it, then hotfix). Test, deploy, then merge the pro tag into the dev branch. Cherry picking into production is IMHO very bad practice (because you don't deploy what you tested).

Comment: Yeh that's what I meant ;)